# Python DataFrame: Add two columns based on minimum and maximum range?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two df's one with `price` and another df with `price ranges`.

```
    price_df

            name       price
    0      anthony       5
    1      paul          16
    2      marcus        25
    3      bruno         45



    range_df

        add_amount     min     max    
    0         10        0       10
    1         20        10      20
    2         30        20      30
    3         40        30      50
```

I'm trying to add amount to price if `price` column falls into that category.
Example:

`name` - `marcus` has price `25`, which falls in between `20-30`, so add 30 to `price`.

```
    Expected output

            name       price     final_amount
    0      anthony       5          15
    1      paul          16         36
    2      marcus        25         55
    3      bruno         45         85
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `pd.cut`:

```
price_bins = [range_df['min'][0]] + list(range_df['max'])

price_df['final_amount'] = price_df['price'] + pd.cut(price_df['price'], 
                                                      bins= price_bins,
                                                      labels=range_df['add_amount']
                                                     ).astype(float)
```

Output:

```
      name  price  final_amount
0  anthony      5          15.0
1     paul     16          36.0
2   marcus     25          55.0
3    bruno     45          85.0
```

Answer (score 0):

another way for your problem:

```
l = [] # creat a list for to add final amount

for i in price_df['price']:
    for j in range(len(range_df['min'])):
        if i < range_df['max'][j] and i > range_df['min'][j]:
            
            l.append(i + range_df['add_amount'][j]) # append the variable between min a max to l
        else:
            print('-->', range_df['add_amount'][j])
            
price_df['final_amount'] = l # make a coulmn named final_amount
```